# get max value for column and the same column for specific record at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement

I have a table like this:

```
_id integer
column_1 text
column_2 integer
```

I want to get value of `column_2` if the `_id = 1` and if not exist get the max value for `column_2`

```
SELECT max(column_2), column_2
where _id = 2
```

this will fail sure, is there a way to get the both values in the same query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
     IFNULL(column_2,l.MValue) 
FROM mytable 
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT 
            id,   
            MAX(column_2) as MValue 
          FROM mytable 
          ) as l ON l.id = mytable.id 
WHERE mytable.id = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7839c/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(column_2, (SELECT MAX(column_2) FROM test)) column2  
FROM test WHERE id = 1;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7839c/25)

Comment: dependant subqueries are slow and joins are faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ( Exist ) SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question right may be be this can help you.

```
select 
    IF(column_2 IS NULL, X.maxv, column_2) 
from test,(select max(column_2) as maxv from test)as X
```