# How to get the max value for a specific column from all tables tables which contains that column name in an oracle schema?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle schema with 5000 tables and I retrieved all the tables with the column name `updt_dt_tm` and `updt_dt_time`. Now I want an additional column which gives me the max of that `updt_dt_tm` or `updt_dt_time` column which is a timestamp column.

currently, my retrieved table looks in this format.

`table_name      column_name
     1            updt_dt_tm
     2            updt_dt_tm
     3           updt_dt_time
     4            updt_dt_tm
     5           updt_dt_time
     6            updt_dt_tm`

To retrieve the above table this is my query which is straight forward.

`select table_name, column_name from all_tab_columns where column_name='updt_dt_tm' or column_name='updt_dt_time' and owner = schema_name.`

I am trying to retrieve a table which looks like

`table_name      column_name       value
     1            updt_dt_tm   max(updt_date_tm)
     2            updt_dt_tm   max(updt_date_tm)
     3           updt_dt_time  max(updt_date_time)
     4            updt_dt_tm   max(updt_date_tm)
     5           updt_dt_time  max(updt_date_time)
     6            updt_dt_tm   max(updt_date_tm)`

I tried a few references from StackOverflow but they aren't working.

[SQL Loop through all tables and get the max value from a specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559293/sql-loop-through-all-tables-and-get-the-max-value-from-a-specific-column)

[get max value for column and the same column for specific record at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171634/get-max-value-for-column-and-the-same-column-for-specific-record-at-the-same-tim)

I'd really appreciate if I can get some help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The links you show are questions about MS Sqlserver and Mysql.  How is that relevant to the question on oracle?

Comment: Having thousands of tables with similar structure like same column may be a sign of a database design problem. Consider migrating like tables into **one** with identifying indicator field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need plsql to achieve this. Something like this:

```
declare
cursor c_tab is
select table_name, column_name 
from all_tab_columns 
where (column_name='updt_dt_tm' or column_name='updt_dt_time') 
and owner = schema_name;

v_sql varchar2(32000);

begin
    for r_tab in c_tab loop
       v_sql := 'select ' || 
                r_tab.table_name || ' table_name, ' || 
                r_tab.column_name || ' column_name, ' || 
                '(select max(' || r_tab.column_name || ') from ' || r_tab.table_name || ') value ' ||
                'from dual';
        execute immediate v_sql;                
    end loop;
end;
```